# Form file input not properly resetting in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, forms

Consider the following example:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form id="test">
      <input type="file">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function reset()
    {
      document.getElementById('test').reset();
    }

    function tell_me()
    {
      console.log( document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value );
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

In most browsers (Chrome, Firefox tested) if you select a file with the input and run `tell_me` it'll give you the name of the file path that's been selected. If you run `reset` beforehand it'll reset the form and then have a blank value for `tell_me`.

In IE11 this isn't the case, and although running `reset` will clear the input on the screen, `tell_me` will still show the file path.

This is a problem because when that form is then submitted, in IE11 the file is still attached.

I know I could destroy and re-create the DOM element to workaround this, but does anyone else know what the root cause is and a solution?

Incidentally, for regular text inputs this isn't a  problem in IE11. Running reset and then grabbing their value gives the expected blank value.

**No jQuery please!**

Comment: Hae you tried document.getElementById("fileinputid").value=""?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap a  script for IE11 if  that is only browser creating the problem,
then on  reset clear the value for the `input file`

```
document.getElementById("fileinputid").value=""
```

and then manualy perform reset for thr form using, as you are doing

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Comment: That does work, thanks. Any idea why IE11 behaves like this? Is it a bug or a behaviour for a specific reason?

Comment: Sorry Matt.. I don't know too.. but will let you know

Comment: Cheers. What is particularly strange is that IE9 doesn't have this issue (haven't tested IE10)